# neural network doesn't fit boundaries

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, modelica, dymola

I'm new to machine learning and trying to fit a sample data set with neural networks in python using tensorflow. After having implemented the neural network in Dymola I want to compare the outputs of the function with those from the neural network.

The sample data set is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import metrics
import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import *
import scipy.io as sio
import mat4py as m4p


inputs = np.linspace(0, 15, num=3000)
outputs = 1/7 * ((inputs/5)^3 - (inputs/3)^2 + 5)
```

Inputs and outputs are then scaled into the interval [0; 0.9]:

```
inputs_max = np.max(inputs)
inputs_min = np.min(inputs)
outputs_max = np.max(outputs)
outputs_min = np.min(outputs)

upper_bound = 0.9
lower_bound = 0

m_in = (upper_bound - lower_bound) / (inputs_max - inputs_min)
c_in = upper_bound - (m_in * inputs_max)
scaled_in = m_in * inputs + c_in

m_out = (upper_bound - lower_bound) / (outputs_max - outputs_min)
c_out = upper_bound - (m_out * outputs_max)
scaled_out = m_in * inputs + c_in
```

and after that the neural network is trained with:

```
# shuffle values

def shuffle_in_unison(a, b):
assert len(a) == len(b)
shuffled_a = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
shuffled_b = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype)
permutation = np.random.permutation(len(a))
for old_index, new_index in enumerate(permutation):
    shuffled_a[new_index] = a[old_index]
    shuffled_b[new_index] = b[old_index]
return shuffled_a, shuffled_b

tf_features_64 = scaled_in
tf_labels_64 = scaled_out
tf_features_32 = tf_features_64.astype(np.float32)
tf_labels_32 = tf_labels_64.astype(np.float32)

X = tf_features_32
Y = tf_labels_32

shuffle_in_unison(X, Y)


# define callbacks

filepath = "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"

savebestCallBack = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)

tbCallBack = TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', 
histogram_freq=5, 
write_graph=True, 
write_images=True)

esCallback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                           min_delta=0,
                           patience=500,
                           verbose=0,
                           mode='min')


# neural network architecture

visible = Input(shape=(1,)) 
x = Dense(40, activation='tanh')(visible) 
x = Dense(39, activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(38, activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(30, activation='tanh')(x) 
output = Dense(1)(x)


# setup optimizer

Optimizer = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0007, amsgrad=True)

model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output) 

model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
                  loss=['mse'],
                  metrics=['mae', 'mse']
                  ) 
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, batch_size=1, verbose=1, 
          shuffle=True, validation_split=0.05, callbacks=[tbCallBack, esCallback])


# return weights

weights1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
biases1 = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1]
print('Layer1---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('weights1:')
print(repr(weights1.transpose()))
print('biases1:')
print(repr(biases1))
w1 = weights1.transpose()
b1 = biases1.transpose()
we1 = {'w1' : w1.tolist()}
bi1 = {'b1' : b1.tolist()}
.........
......
```

Later on, I implemented the trained neural network in the program "Dymola" by loading the weights and biases in pre-configured "neural network base classes" (which have been used several times and are working).

```
// Modelica code for Dymola:

Real inputs;
Real outputs;
Real scaled_outputs;
Real scaled_inputs(start=0);
Real scaled_outputsfunc;
der(scaled_inputs) = 0.9;


//part of the neural network implementation in Dymola

NeuralNetwork.BaseClasses.NeuralNetworkLayer neuralNetworkLayer1(
NeuronActivationFunction=NeuralNetwork.Types.ActivationFunction.TanSig,
numInputs=1,
numNeurons=40,
weightTable=[-0.367953330278397; ......])
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-76,22},{-56,42}})));

//scaled inputs
neuralNetworkLayer1.u[1] = scaled_inputs;

//scaled outputs
neuralNetworkLayer5.y[1]= scaled_outputs;

//scaled_inputs = 0.06 * inputs
inputs = 1/0.06 * (scaled_inputs);

outputs = 1/875 * inputs^3 - 1/63 * inputs^2 + 5/7;

scaled_outputsfunc = 1.2173139581825052 * outputs - 0.3173139581825052;
```

When plotting and comparing the scaled outputs of the function and the returned (scaled) values of the neural network I noticed that the approximation is very good in the interval from [0.5; 0.8], but the closer the inputs reach the boundaries the worse the approximation becomes.

Unfortunately, I have no clue why this is happening and how to fix this issue. I'd be very glad if someone could help me.

Comment: I would be very interested to talk to you about the implementation of tensorflow in modelica!!

Comment: Are you talking about the implementation of a neural network in modelica or of tensorflow in particular?

Comment: NN in Modelica!

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: what resources have you used to implement the NN ?

Comment: The training is done in tensorflow, in Dymola I'm just using neural network base classes in which weights/biases/activation functions/neurons/inputs are stored.

Comment: Ah I see for some reason thought you used the tensorflow library somehow in Dymola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question: I forgot to specify the activation function in the output layer in my python code, which Keras then set to a linear function by default, see also:

https://keras.io/layers/core/

In Dymola, where my ANN was implemented, 'tanh' was the activation function in the last layer, which lead to a divergence near the boundaries.

The correct python code for this application must be:

```
visible = Input(shape=(1,)) 
x = Dense(40, activation='tanh')(visible) 
x = Dense(39, activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(38, activation='tanh')(x) 
x = Dense(30, activation='tanh')(x) 
output = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(x)
```